# Datastax Enterprise license pricing per node

Tags: licensing, datastax-enterprise

We have a cluster of 5 node. Since datastax community edition doesn't offer reliable technical support, we are planning to purchase datastax enterprise.

I would like to know cost of the datastax enterprise license per node.

Comment: This might help: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-per-node-price-for-a-DataStax-enterprise-subscription